# Spring Boot Data JPA - query using an interface projection returns all fields if there are collections in the projection

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, projection

There are several entities in the project, such as User and enum Role, which is used in the User entity as @ElementCollection.

**User entity**

```
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 80)
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean isActive = false;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = LAZY)
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>(Set.of(USER));
}
```

**Role enum**

```
public enum Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    USER, ADMIN;
    
    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return name();
    }
}
```

For the User entity, I created a special projection that includes the following fields, including the role collection:

```
public interface UserProjection {
    String getUsername();
    String getPassword();
    Set<Role> getRoles();
}
```

And a JPA repository with a method that finds by username the user using this projection:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"roles"})
    Optional<UserProjection> findUserByUsername(String username);
}
```

When I call this method, I run into the problem that the query contains all fields, including those not specified in the projection:

```
select
        user0_.id as id1_1_,
        user0_.email as email2_1_,
        user0_.is_active as is_activ3_1_,
        user0_.password as password4_1_,
        user0_.username as username5_1_,
        roles1_.users_id as users_id1_2_0__,
        roles1_.roles as roles2_2_0__ 
    from
        users user0_ 
    left outer join
        users_roles roles1_ 
            on user0_.id=roles1_.users_id 
    where
        user0_.username=?
```

But if I remove the collection from the projection, the query starts working correctly:

```
select
        user0_.username as col_0_0_,
        user0_.password as col_1_0_ 
    from
        users user0_ 
    where
        user0_.username=?
```

Can you tell me how to fix this error? I couldn't find any clues, including in the Spring Data JPA documentation, which gave examples of the most basic use cases of projections. Thanks